# WPF Databinding to ComboBox and also toggle its visibility

Tags: wpf

There are two issues that iam facing. One is binding a collection to combobox

In code:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> errList;
```

Initially its empty and then i add items to it.

In XAML:

```
<comboBox ItemsSource="{Binding errList}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
```

Isnt this enough to get it done. But no items are seen in the combobox.

Second is toggling the visibility of the combobox when items are present.

```
<combobox Visibility="{ Binding ElementName=Page1, Path=ItemsPresent, Converter={StaticResource booltoVis} }"
```

ItemsPresent is a property which returns true of errList has items more than 0. But this is not working.

Please Help

Comment: Wasn't sure if you knew this or not, but viewing your 'Output' window (in VS) while debugging will show details on any issues with your Bindings.  This can be very useful, just wanted to make sure you were aware of it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can bind to a private field, instead after filling your collection you can do the following:

```
YourComboBoxName.ItemsSource = errList;
```

For the visibility you need to do self binding like this:

```
<ComboBox Visibility="{Binding Path=ItemsPresent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource booltoVis}}"/>
```

Comment: +1, You can only bind to Properties. You could only bind to a private field using code behind. However, what @A_Nablsi is showing is not a "binding" but rather a simple assignment.